# Upgrading mobo and CPU without reinstall (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, hardware

I have a workstation with Ubuntu 9.04 running on it. I am looking to upgrade it to another cpu/motherboard. What should I expect after I boot it up after upgrade? Will full reinstall be required?

**Current system:**

Intel Core 2 Q6600,
Abit IP35 Pro,
4x750Gb SATA2 drives in RAID10 software array

**New system:**

Core i7 920,
ASUS P6T Deluxe V2,
Same 4x750Gb SATA2 drives in RAID10 software array :)

PS: I realize that this is not a server(in a full sense) related issue, however I hope it is not offtopic either :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is very likely that you can just move the drives from the old system to the new system (or replace the motherboard in the existing system) and when it boots up it will work perfectly with no changes required.

if any changes are required, they will be minimal - almost trivial - tweaks.  unless you somehow manage to destroy your drives, you will NOT need to do a full reinstall.

if you're using the stock ubuntu kernel then it should auto-detect the network card and load the appropriate driver.

it will probably autodetect the video card too and load the right driver for X.  if you're running it text-only or headless, there's no chance of any problem there.

your drives are sata, with software raid0.  again, the kernel should auto-load the right drivers even if the sata chipset has changed.

Overall, it should Just Work.

(of course, it never hurts to backup.  it's better to waste a small amount of time than all your data)

I've lost count of the number of times that I've upgraded machines like this.  It's usually a very straight-forward, no-fuss procedure.

Comment: Worse case scenario you could compile a new kernel with the required modules. That really is the worse case scenario :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes your harddrive controller won't be recognized by the installed system, and thus the kernel won't mount the file system. However, Ubuntu has this pretty well taken care of except with the most esoteric controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Without more details on the current and future hardware we can't give you an answer we're certain of. Given you HAVE to back it up first right, why not do that, perform the in-place update and come back to inform us for future reference?

Comment: yep, I'll post info about my progress here :) but just wanted to know if there are obvious things I should do/know about(well except for backup of course :)

Answer (score 0):

Run the Install CD in Live CD mode first, and if all the hardware is detected properly (i.e. by the kernel), you *probably* won't have much to worry about.

As Chopper3 recommends, backup backup backup.

All of your packages should remain installed. The partitions will be the same, etc., so I'd say you're probably good to go. But do a test run with LiveCD.

Answer (score 0):

Expect your network and video cards will need to be reconfigured

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly(to me at least) I needed no changes to the system whatsoever. It booted up on a new hardware with no problems. I had to reconfigure X server with dpkg-reconfigure to output to proper monitor, but other than that - no changes were required.